# Steady states in a differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the following model

$$\begin{cases} \frac{du}{d\tau} = \beta u \big(1- \frac{u}{v}\big)\\
\frac{dv}{d\tau} = v(1-v) - \alpha uv
\end{cases}$$

where $\alpha, \beta \geq 0$.

I'm trying to calculate and determine the stability of the steady states. The only one I can find though is $(u,v) = (0,1)$.

I've tried letting $\dot{u} = \dot{v} = 0$ but it doesn't make things easier.

Comment: Apparently your question is actually to **find** the equilibria, not to study their properties. "I've tried letting $\dot{u} = \dot{v} = 0$ but it doesn't make things easier." Yes this is the way, how did it fail to go through?

Comment: I begin by letting $\beta u(1-\frac{u}{v}) = v(1-v) - \alpha uv$ but i'm unsure what to do, there doesn't appear to be a way of making either variable the subject. Also, once the equilibria is found the question is asking what is the nature of the equilibria (ie. unstable, stable spiral etc.)

Comment: You tried to solve $\dot u=\dot v$ instead of $\dot u=\dot v=0$. Let us try to be slightly more serious, shall we?

Comment: My apologies. It's a new topic we're learning and i was just a bit confused with the different notations people are using. I've found $\dot{u}$ to give v = u and resubstituted to find the two steady states; $(0,0), (\frac{1}{1-a},\frac{1}{1-a})$. Hopefully this is correct! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

This differential system is found in population dynamics.

You will find a general setting in the excellent document "Modeling Population Dynamics" (https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/a.m.deroos/downloads/pdf_readers/syllabus.pdf): see equations (7.2) page 137.